# CSS not loaded on PC

Tags: css, mobile

I 've just finished my media queries and everything's fine on mobile devices.  Problem came up when testing on real PC, and real viewports.  No 404, no error, CSS's validated via jigsaw, added and removed slashes on href's, css files are visible and linkeable, etc.  Been reading many questions similar to this one of mine but without any results.  Using chrome dev tools so let's see the code, ok?

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta content="#1C002A" name="theme-color"/>
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
<meta content="black-translucent" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style">
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="true" name="HandheldFriendly">
<meta content="width" name="MobileOptimized">
<link href="/assets/css/minima.css" media="screen and (max-width: 566px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/css/567minima.css" media="screen and (min-width: 567px) and (max-width: 767px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/css/768minima.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/css/960minima.css" media="screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/1200minima.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1200px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After that codeblock ther's only a manifest.json and head closing tag.
Pure html, vanilla javascript, no less/sass, no ext libraries.

Comment: does it work if you just link a css file without the media query?

Comment: try delete the browser's cache.

Comment: I think ./assets will solve your issue.

Comment: Yes Huangism.  In fact minima.css is in charge of color schemes and plain html tags modifications. It's the only file that works in PC besides its width rule, I'll take a look, tyvm.
AM77 cache deleted even manually.  Besides using no cache addon and .htaccess contains cache control.
Dejazmach.  Tried it, but no results either. Tyvm.

Comment: Restarted server.  Tested via 127.0.0.1 and it worked!
Thanks a lot guys!  Weird things happen sometimes.
I appreciate a lot your help.   :)